# Do particles lose energy when they emit gravitons?

Tags: gravity, energy-conservation

Is everything in the universe very slowly decaying due to gravity, do particles lose energy when they emit a graviton and gain energy if they happen to absorb a graviton?

Comment: 1)no (fundamental particles do not decay) 2)yes (the graviton must be a spin-2 boson)

Comment: 1) We don't know if there are any stable particles. 2) It's not clear that gravitons even exist. 3) Why the discrepancy between Bruce Smitherson and me? Because he gave the correct theoretical answers and I am adding the correct experimental ones.

Comment: In theory has anyone worked out what would happen if particles were decaying due to gravity? or experimentally is the energy of theorized graviton so small that it would be insignificant even after a trillion years?

Comment: Ps. I'd add (4) We don't know if gravitons are acting on particles or acting on space itself;-)

Comment: Pps. From a conservative point of view we are 99.99995% sure they do exist. http://motls.blogspot.com.au/2015/09/gr-qg-horizons-gravitational-waves.html?m=1

Comment: I would suggest to avoid blogs for research into "existence" of scientific notions. Lubos is a very smart guy, but he is extremely opinionated about a few things. "Existence" statements in physics require unambiguous experimental detection. No such thing has been done for gravitons (or even gravitational waves). Even the existence of gravitational waves would say nothing about the existence of gravitons. Water waves obviously exist but there is no such thing as a "waterwaveton" because water is frozen at temperatures at which its linearized acoustic excitations would show a quantum nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between real and virtual gravitons.

A [gravitational wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) can in principle be represented as a superposition or real gravitons, just as an electromagnetic wave can be represented as a superposition of real photons. A gravitational wave carries energy, just as an electromagnetic wave does, so if a system is generating gravitational waves then those waves will be carrying energy away from the system. For example this is what causes the slowdown in a [Hulse Taylor binary pulsar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_B1913%2B16). So in this sense a system does lose energy when it emits gravitons.

Virtual gravitons are a computational device used in a perturbative calculation of scattering in a quantum field theory of gravity. Virtual gravitons do not exist as particles - they are just a mathematical device like virtual photons or indeed any virtual particle. So a system cannot usefully be said to be losing energy by emitting virtual gravitons.

An isolated particle does not emit gravitational waves because that requires an oscillating quadrupole. While it may be represented as continuously emitting and absorbing virtual gravitons, these do not carry away an energy. So an isolated particle will not decay by any gravitational mechanism.